# Kronecker factorization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, kronecker-product

I have found [in a paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4655362) the following identities (equations $(119)$, $(120)$, appendix D):
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i,j=1}^s p_{ij} d_i d_j'X &= \begin{bmatrix}d_1 \\ \vdots \\ d_s\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}d_1'X & \cdots &d_s'X\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}p_{11}I_d & \cdots & p_{1s}I_d \\
\vdots & & \vdots\\
p_{s1}I_d & \cdots & p_{ss}I_d
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}d_1 \\ \vdots \\ d_s\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}d_1' & \cdots &d_s'\end{bmatrix}(P\otimes X)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
where:

1. $d_1$, ..., $d_s$ are column vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{d\times 1}$;
2. $X$ is a symmetric and positively definite square matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$;
3. $I_d$ is the $d\times d$ identity matrix;
4. $P$ is a symmetric and positively definite square matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{s\times s}$ whos structure is
   \begin{equation}P\triangleq \begin{bmatrix}p_{11}& \cdots & p_{1s}\\
   \vdots & & \vdots \\
   p_{s1}& \cdots & p_{ss}
   \end{bmatrix}\end{equation}
5. $\otimes$ denotes the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Definition);
6. $'$ denotes the transpose operator (thus $d_i'$ is a row vector in $\mathbb{R}^{1\times d}$).

I'm not sure, but in my opinion these relations are not true: the first member seems to be a summation of $s^2$ different $d\times d$ matrices, while the second member (and also the third member) seems to be a $sd\times sd$ matrix. Thus, the equalities cannot hold.

Answer (score 2):

Indexed vectors are a pain. But here is a simple result that always helps me untangle them.

Let $(A,B)$ be matrices whose columns are $(a_i,b_j)$ respectively, and let $Y$ be an arbitrary matrix with elements $(y_{ij})$ whose dimension are compatible. Then
$$\eqalign{
AYB^T = \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n y_{ij}a_ib_j^T \\
}$$
Apply this to the matrices of the current problem by substituting
$A=B=D,\;Y=P,\;$ and $\,m=n=s$.
$$\eqalign{
DPD^T = \sum_{i=1}^s\sum_{j=1}^s p_{ij}d_id_j^T \\
}$$
Therefore the entire expression is simply $\,DPD^TX$

---

NB: You are correct. The given relationship ***cannot*** be correct. What they are proposing is
$$
\def\v{{\rm vec}}
\Big(\v(D)\otimes\v(D)^T\Big)\big(P\otimes X\big)
$$
which is an interesting quantity, but does not match the dimensions of the original sum.